# JsPlumb - drop Icon with Endpoints on already existing Connector line

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, jsplumb

[image]
The desired behaviour is that on drop on connector - we want to have this icon connected with Endpoints of others two Icons.
I don't think that there is a build solution for such behaviour in jsPlumb, but maybe I'm wrong.
 I see oportunity to make it programically.
At first I thought about mouseup event from [documentation](https://jsplumbtoolkit.com/community/doc/events.html#connectionEvents).
It doesn't work since actually I mouseup on this orange icon HTML element. The conector is underneath. If there is no way to have this event - also the full detail of area of connector would be helpful.